# Very very basic query on programming in C -- displaying int value

Tags: c, int

When I compile this little program instead of displaying "`num1:7` , `num2: 2`",
it displays "`num1:-1218690218` , `num2:-1217453276`". I think I'm not specifying what the program should display so its just giving me the int range instead.
I'm sorry.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
     int num1 = 7, num2 = 2;                
     printf("num1:%d , num2:%d\n"), num1, num2;
}
```

EDIT: Thank you so much! The purpose of the exercise was to correct syntax errors, but whenever I compiled it I never got any warnings. That parenthesis is so easy to miss.

Comment: Please turn on your compilers warnings and read them.

Comment: Don't be sorry for asking a question! This is well phrased, includes a code sample, and your mistake could help others in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've put the closing parenthesis *before* `num1` and `num2`, so they're not being passed to `printf`. You need to change this:

```
 printf("num1:%d , num2:%d\n"), num1, num2;
```

to this:

```
 printf("num1:%d , num2:%d\n", num1, num2);
```

Yes, the parenthesis is the only change, but it's crucial.

Answer (score 5):

You are using the comma operator instead of arguments to a function call. `printf` will output garbage values but it could have crashed as well.

---

So it should be:

```
printf("num1:%d , num2:%d\n", num1, num2);
```

Notice the `)`-character.

Answer (score 4):

You want to move `num1` and `num2` inside your parentheses:

```
printf("num1:%d , num2:%d\n", num1, num2);
```

The reason is that `num1` and `num2` are part of the call to the `printf` function - without them, `printf` uses random data from elsewhere, giving you those large negative values.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
     int num1 = 7, num2 = 2;                
     printf("num1:%d , num2:%d\n", num1, num2);
     //                                      ^ num1 and num2 go inside the parentheses
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If that is the actual code then fix it by moving the paren.

```
printf("num1:%d , num2:%d\n", num1, num2);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your program should look more like this

```
int main(){
int num1 = 7, num2 = 2;
printf("num1 : %d num2 : %d\n",num1,num2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use a compiler that checks your syntax something like pellesc for windows

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int num1 = 7, num2 = 2;
printf("num1:%d , num2:%d\n", num1, num2);
return 0;
}
```

your printf format was wrong something a c editor would have told you

Comment: I was connecting to my school through SSH; they run a linux system so I was just using the cc command. That's probably why it didn't give me warnings. Ty.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that `printf` is looking at numbers in memory adjacent to the memory the program is working in (the stack). These numbers are there for some other reason when `printf` just happens to look at them, so it prints them instead of `num1` and `num2`. As others have pointed out, your arguments (`num1` and `num2`) need to be inside of the parentheses so that `printf` can use them.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>  
int main()
  {  
    //int num1 = 7, num2 = 2; this is static intialisation
    //u want it as dynamic u have to use 
    int num1,num2;
    scanf("%d%d",&num1,&num2); //get the values from user 
    printf("num1:%d , num2:%d\n", num1, num2); 
    return 0; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you wanted was "call `printf` with this format string, using `num1` as the first value to substitute in and `num2` as the second value to substitute in; ignore the value that `printf` returns". (`printf` normally returns a count of how many bytes it printed; the actual printing is a side effect.)

What you wrote was "call `printf` with this format string; ignore the value that it returns, and evaluate `num1`; ignore that value and evaluate `num2`; ignore that value". This is undefined behaviour: `printf` hasn't been given any values to substitute in, and will normally blindly reach around in memory for the values that it's expecting to receive (sometimes resulting in a crash) - but the language standard says your program is allowed to do **literally anything** at this point. Yes, this is a very dangerous language to be working with :)

To pass the values to `printf`, they need to be within the parentheses, as illustrated in other answers.